# How can I prove that a singularity is removable, a pole, etc.?

Tags: singularity-theory, singularity

Let's sy I have something like $f(z)=\frac{z^6+1}{z^2+1}$. I know that the singularity is at $z=\pm i$ and that it ends up being a $\frac{0}{0}$ case, but is that an indication for what type of singularity it is? A similar example on a wiki page said that this type of case is a removable singularity and the case of $\frac{1}{0}$ like for $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$ is a simple pole.

Is that the only way by which one can tell which type of singularity it is?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as long as $z \neq \pm i$, we have
$$
f(z) = \frac{z^6+1}{z^2 + 1} = \frac{(z^2 + 1)(z^4 - z^2 + 1)}{z^2 + 1} = z^4 - z^2 + 1
$$
which means the singularities are very much removable.

You can't be too certain about the type of pole from a $\frac00$ expression, though. For instance, $\frac{z^3}z$ has a pole of degree $2$ at the origin.

Comment: So, the only way of knowing if it's removable is to find a different expression for the term in the hope that it cancels out with the dominator in this case? Is there a general rule of thumb other than this? Because I don't think I would be able to think up of a different expression every time I have such a function to solve. Great answer though, thanks.

Comment: @Rab You can also try to evaluate the limit of $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches the singularity. If $|f(z)|$ goes toward infinity, then it's a pole of some degree. If $f(z)$ goes to some finite limit, then it's a removable singularity. And if it behaves like crazy, then it's an essential singularity.

Comment: @Rab: "behaves like crazy" in Arthur's comment means that for each $l \in \Bbb C$, you may find a sequence $z_n \to z_0$ such that $f(z_n) \to l$. This shows that $f$ doesn't even have a limit in $z_0$.